Old lady protects circus freaks in her house
It's a B movie to be sure, Late 70's or 80's. Anyway this old lady protects circus type freaks at her house in secret. One of the freaks is just a head in a box in the attic. If someone hurts a freak somewhere they all go out and get revenge. One of the actors is a "normal' pretty woman who happen to be pregnant with a kid who won't leave lol... I talked about this movie with someone who saw it too and we just can't remember the name.

Sounds like Basket Case 2 from 1990, the sequel to the cult horror film from 1982 about a man who has a murderous, deformed siamese twin called Belial. From IMDb:

Duane Bradley and his misshapen, basket-dwelling brother Belial are taken to the city hospital. [...] Duane's long-lost Aunt learns of their situation and, along with her pregnant daughter Susan, helps them escape from the confines of the hospital and the eye of the press. [The] aunt, known as Granny Ruth, takes them under her wing at her mansion, which serves as a safe haven for hideously deformed freaks of all shapes and sizes.

Belial is basically a head in a box and Granny Ruth's daughter Susan has been pregnant for 6 years. Here's the trailer:



